# Dock background disappears. Bug or trouble?

Tags: macos, dock

It's already the second time that this occurs. I switch from one user to another and the dock has no background. It looks pretty cool but I don't understand if there's a problem on my hard drive setup or if it's a bug. 
I have 10.8.5. Has anyone else experienced this behavior?

This only happens with the new account that I start up as a switch from the old one. The installation is rather new on new hardware.

Note: if I kill the dock from a terminal window, the background comes back. Still...

[image]

Comment: Kill applications one by one to start troubleshooting.

Comment: both ways or one account specific ?

Comment: @Buscar웃: one account, the new one that I start up as a switch from the old one. The installation is rather new on new hardware.